# Ubuntu Server , Installed Hdd into another computer and now have no internet connection

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, ifconfig

EDIT: NVRM I figured it out on my own.. I needed to edit a file and remove the Previous eth0 and then rename my eth1 to eth0. 
I would like to set a static IP adress though if anyone wants to help me out with that.

I will start off by saying that I am a complete newcomer to Linux. With that said though I am learning and I will try my best to do what I can.

I set up a cheap linux server using an old desktop computer to run a game server for a video game my friends and I play.

The server only had 2gb of ram though and it just wasn't cutting it. The mother board only had 2 slots and I only had 1gb sticks.

So I took the HDD with linux still installed on it and put it into another desktop I have that has 4 memory slots so I could have 4gb of RAM.

The thing is though now that I have moved the HDD OS and all to another computer with a diff motherboard the internet is not working. I can't get an Ip address with the /sbin/ifconfig command.

I need to be able to connect to the server of course so this isn't to good.

Its connected to a router and the router is using DHCP. I assume that since the HDD was in another computer with a different motherboard the Network adaptor information is still for that motherboard?

I'm not sure how linux handles that stuff..Also when I start Linux a message appears at boot screen that says "Waiting for network configuration"

If anyone could reccomend some steps for me to take I would greatly appreciate it. 
Thanks!
EDIT: researching it some more it seems it probably renamed the new network adaptor to eth1 since there was already an eth0 from the previous motherboard. If do a ip addr show eth0 it says there is no eth0. I have no idea how to fix this though. From looking around it seems I need to make changes to a file?

Answer (score 0):

To setup static IP, we need to edit the `interfaces` file

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

The current entry would look like

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

You will need you need to change this to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.x.x
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.0.0
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

You will have to change the addresses around depending on your network.

Then restart networking using `sudo service networking restart`. If that gives you trouble reboot the machine.

If your router is using DHCP, you can also consider to configure the router to assign a particular static IP to the server.